# Brave browser, have autocomplete top browser in address bar

Tags: google-chrome, browser, autocomplete, brave

[image: brave]

I've setup Google as the default search engine and expected to have autocomplete like in Chrome. I tried googling a solution but from the scattered links I could find, I could not find a solution.

Below is Chrome's dropdown. It'd expect to get the same or similar results.

p.s. I'm giving an example with google as the default Search engine, but the same goes for DuckDuckGo. Autocomplete when I go to the actual page and not in the browser's address bar.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable "Autocomplete searches and URLs" in `chrome://settings/?search=Autocomplete%20searches%20and%20URLs`

Answer (score 0):

Visit the below links and follow the steps:

1. brave://settings/privacy : Enable "Autocomplete searches and URLs"
2. brave://settings/appearance : Enable "Show autocomplete in address bar"
3. brave://settings/search : Pick your search engine (Google & Bing will give you upto 9 autocomplete results while Brave & DuckDuckGo will give you upto 3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).